# Arcade physics rotation and angularVelocity

Tags: phaser-framework

So ... what exactly are the parameters of body.rotation and body.angularVelocity in Phaser arcade physics?

The documentation for body.rotation just says "the amount the Body is rotated", without specifying units (radians or degrees), the zero vector (X axis?), nor the direction that's positive.

Docs for body.angle says "angle in radians" ... but again doesn't say which axis is the 0 rotation vector, nor which direction is positive.

The documentation for angularVelocity says "angular velocity in pixels per second squared" which doesn't make ANY SENSE AT ALL.  You can't measure rotation in pixels.

I'm trying to sync up a phaser front-end with a server-based physics model that has its own coordinate system, so some clarity on the documentation would really make my life easier!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "body.rotation" is given in radians and if using degrees you should use "body.angle".

For the rotation direction a higher value rotates the sprite clockwise. If the angle is 0 and the sprite is pointing up it will point to the right after entering the body.angle = 90.

angularVelocity is not for rotating your sprite. The name says "angularVELOCITY" so what it's used for is to set an angular velocity. It's mainly used when you want the sprite to move in the direction it's facing.